# Jboss Spring CXF client Stream is closed error

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf, cxf-client

Have been trying to get this to work since 2 days, but failing miserably to do so

Here is my bean config:

```
<jaxws:client id="helloClient"
    serviceClass="com.somepackage.ServicePort"
    address="http://path/to/deployed/service">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logIn" />
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOut" />
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>
<bean id="logIn" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
<bean id="logOut" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
```

I injected helloClient in another bean to invoke the service:
But this is the error I'm getting:

```
   15:58:05,275 INFO  [STDOUT] 90378 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl  - Invoke, operation info:
 [BindingOperationInfo: {http://path/to/deployed/service}checkService],
 params: [com.somepackage.CheckServiceRequestType@7ef4ec00]
 15:58:05,275 INFO  [STDOUT] 90378 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl  - set requestContext to message
 be{java.lang.reflect.Method=public abstract
 com.somepackage.CheckServiceResponseType
 com.somepackage.ServicePort.checkService(com.somepackage.CheckServiceRequestType)
 throws com.somepackage.FaultInfo,
 org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext.SCOPES={org.apache.cxf.message.Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS=APPLICATION},
 org.apache.cxf.message.Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS=http://path to
 service} 15:58:05,275 INFO  [STDOUT] 90378 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25]
 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl  - Interceptors contributed
 by bus: [] 15:58:05,275 INFO  [STDOUT] 90378 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25]
 DEBUG org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl  - Interceptors contributed
 by client: [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor@5abd4570]
 15:58:05,275 INFO  [STDOUT] 90378 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl  - Interceptors contributed by
 endpoint:
 [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@4019ea9a,
 org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.SwAOutInterceptor@65794556,
 org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor@7cb74525,
 org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderOutInterceptor@641cc01a]
 15:58:05,275 INFO  [STDOUT] 90378 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl  - Interceptors contributed by
 binding:
 [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor@1b881e4f,
 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutInterceptor@57de2a8,
 org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor@bab8669,
 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor@2a055d7b,
 org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor@463c4bca,
 org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor@2093decc]
 15:58:05,275 INFO  [STDOUT] 90378 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl  - Interceptors contributed by
 databinding: [] ......

 15:58:05,291 INFO  [STDOUT] 90394 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.ConfigurerImpl  - Could not find a
 definition for bean with id http://http://path/to/deployed/service -
 no injection will be performed. 15:58:05,291 INFO  [STDOUT] 90394
 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit  - Conduit
 '{http://path/to/deployed/service}ServicePortPort.http-conduit' has
 been (re)configured for plain http. 15:58:05,291 INFO  [STDOUT] 90394
 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit  - No Trust Decider
 configured for Conduit
 '{http://path/to/deployed/service}ServicePortPort.http-conduit'
 15:58:05,291 INFO  [STDOUT] 90394 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit  - No Auth Supplier
 configured for Conduit
 '{http://path/to/deployed/service}ServicePortPort.http-conduit'
 15:58:05,291 INFO  [STDOUT] 90394 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit  - Conduit
 '{http://path/to/deployed/service}ServicePortPort.http-conduit' has
 been configured for plain http. 15:58:05,291 INFO  [STDOUT] 90394
 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit  - registering incoming
 observer: org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl@5e9daefe

 .......
     15:58:05,400 INFO  [STDOUT] 90503 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Headers  - Accept: */* 15:58:05,400 INFO
 [STDOUT] 90503 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Headers  - SOAPAction: "checkService"
 15:58:05,415 INFO  [STDOUT] 90518 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.transport.http.TrustDecisionUtil  - No Trust Decider
 for Conduit
 '{http://path/to/deployed/service}ServicePortPort.http-conduit'. An
 afirmative Trust Decision is assumed. 15:58:05,431 INFO  [STDOUT]
 90534 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit  - Sending POST Message with
 Headers to http://path/to/deployed/service Conduit
 :{http://path/to/deployed/service}ServicePortPort.http-conduit
 Content-Type: null 15:58:05,431 INFO  [STDOUT] 90534
 [http-127.0.0.1-8080-25] DEBUG
 org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain  - Invoking handleFault on
 interceptor
 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor@7cb04e98

 .... 15:58:05,431 INFO  [STDOUT] 15:58:05,431 WARN 
 [PhaseInterceptorChain] Interceptor for
 {http://path/to/deployed/service}ServicePortService#{http://path/to/deployed/service}checkService
 has thrown exception, unwinding now org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault:
 Could not send Message.    at
 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at
 org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:484)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:414)   at
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:317)     at
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:269)
 15:58:05,431 INFO  [STDOUT] 15:58:05,431 WARN  [PhaseInterceptorChain]
 Interceptor for
 {http://path/to/deployed/service}ServicePortService#{http://path/to/deployed/service}checkService
 has thrown exception, unwinding now org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault:
 Could not send Message.    at
 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at
 org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:484)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:414)   at
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:317)     at
 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:269)
```

Pretty much stuck with this

Comment: is this url correct `http://path/to/deployed/service` or you have replaced the content in logs?

Comment: I had to replace the service url. But yes the service is deployed and works when I test it with soap UI. Even a simple invocation from  main()  method using JaxWSProxyFactory works.